# Gradle: Unable to integrate Hibernate as a dependency

Tags: hibernate, gradle

I just want to integrate Hibernate as a dependency in my build. But instead of integrating all submodules I desided to integrade the whole hibernate project (`org.hibernate:hibernate:3.5.1-Final`)

The problem: No modules where loaded.

**My `build.gradle`**

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  mavenRepo urls: "http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss"
}

dependencies {
  compile "org.hibernate:hibernate:3.5.1-Final"
}
```

**Output of `gradle build`**

```
Download http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/hibernate/hibernate/3.5.1-Final/hibernate-3.5.1-Final.pom
Download http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/hibernate/hibernate-parent/3.5.1-Final/hibernate-parent-3.5.1-Final.pom
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you're familiar with Maven. Care to post a pom.xml that does what you want your build.gradle to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to specify submodules like these declarations from a working project https://github.com/nabeelalimemon/Gradle-enterprise-multiProject-/blob/master/domain/build.gradle

hibernateVersion = '3.6.0.Final' though.

Then you'll come across issues like slf4j/log4j provision etc and for that just take a look at the master build.gradle of the same hosted project.

Comment: OK, in other words: There is no way to fetch all modules definde in the `<modules>`-Tag of a maven `pom` automatically?

Comment: You can try maven plugin for gradle though. I guess that'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) You said 3.5.1-Final in the heading of your question, but it says 3.5.3-Final in your build.gradle. 
2) Try to switch "public-jboss" by just "public" in the maven repo URL

The final URL will look like this:

http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/hibernate/hibernate/3.5.1-Final/hibernate-3.5.1-Final.pom

or

http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/hibernate/hibernate/3.5.3-Final/hibernate-3.5.3-Final.pom

Comment: Oh sorry! I tried some other versions and mixed 3.5.1 and 3.5.3 in the question. To your anwer: this dosen't help. BTW the responded poms are both equal.